# Ruby to Javascript => Date calculation headaches

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to rewrite the following Ruby snippet to JavaScript, but the output is not what I'm expecting.

This is the original Ruby code:

```
require 'date'
moment = DateTime.new(2014, 9, 27, 0, 0, 0, DateTime.now.offset)
intervals = [['day', 1], ['hour', 24], ['minute', 60], ['second', 60]]
elapsed = DateTime.now - moment
tense = elapsed > 0 ? 'since' : 'until'
interval = 1.0
parts = intervals.collect do |name, new_interval|
  interval /= new_interval
  number, elapsed = elapsed.abs.divmod(interval)
  "#{number.to_i} #{name}#{'s' unless number == 1}"
end
puts "#{parts.join(', ')} #{tense} that moment."
```

This would output something along the lines of "x days, x hours, x seconds since that moment."

The current JavaScript code I have is:

```
// Input: Nov 18 19:01:41 2014 MST
var since = function(date) {
  var elapsed, interval, intervals, parts, tense;
  date = Date.parse(date);
  intervals = [['day', 1], ['hour', 24], ['minute', 60], ['second', 60]];
  elapsed = (new Date).getTime() - date;
  tense = elapsed > 0 ? 'since' : 'until';
  interval = 1.0;
  parts = intervals.map(function(item) {
    var number;
    interval /= item[1];
    number = elapsed % interval;
    elapsed = Math.floor(elapsed / interval);
    return number + " " + item[0] + (number !== 1 ? 's' : void 0);
  });
  return console.log(parts.join(', ') + " " + tense);
};
```

This however, instead of the expected output, gives me something completely nonsensical:

```
0 days, 2.187114859220074e-7 hours, 0.000011154285782022377 minutes, 0.0000022063280195997896 seconds since that moment.
```

I tried to do `elapsed /= 1000`, but the output is still not the one that is expected.

Comment: You likely need a .toFixed in a few places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in code below for fixes:

```
var since = function(date) {
  var elapsed, interval, intervals, parts, tense;
  date = Date.parse(date);    
  intervals = [['day', 1], ['hour', 24], ['minute', 60], ['second', 60]];
  elapsed = (new Date).getTime() - date;

  // "elapsed" is in milliseconds when it was in days (Rational) in the
  // Ruby version. Fix:
  elapsed = elapsed / 1000 / 3600 / 24;

  tense = elapsed > 0 ? 'since' : 'until';
  interval = 1.0;

  parts = intervals.map(function(item) {
    var number;
    interval /= item[1];

    // You mixed "number" with "elapsed", and calculated them in
    // the wrong order. Fix:
    number  = Math.floor(elapsed / interval);
    elapsed = elapsed % interval;

    return number + " " + item[0] + (number !== 1 ? 's' : '');
  });

  return console.log(parts.join(', ') + " " + tense);
};

since('Sep 27 19:01:41 2014 MST');
97 days, 15 hours, 33 minutes, 21 seconds since
```

Comment: I knew there was something else! Note to self: Ruby's dates use days for units

Comment: There are libraries for this. Check out moment.js (http://momentjs.com) and later.js (http://bunkat.github.io/later/) if you are doing scheduling.